# ARQUIVO CSV não grava todos os dados no banco

Tags: php, sql, csv

Boa noite, no meu código quando envio o arquivo CSV Ele grava apenas a última linha do arquivo, quando uso o TRUNCATE TABLE. Sem o truncate grava todas as linhas, mas o objetivo é atualizar os dados apagando eles e inserindo novos. Alguém pode me auxiliar? Segue código:

if(isset($_FILES["arquivo"]))
{
if(isset($_FILES["arquivo"]))
{
$arquivonome = $_FILES["arquivo"]["name"];
$arquivotipo = $_FILES["arquivo"]["type"];
$arquivotmp_name = $_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"];
$arquivotamanho = $_FILES["arquivo"]["size"];
}

```
}


$arquivo = fopen($arquivotmp_name, "r");

while(($dados= fgetcsv($arquivo,1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $chapa = $dados[0];
        $departamento = $dados[1];
        $setor = $dados[2];
        
        
        $query1 = "TRUNCATE TABLE tabela"; //apaga todos os dados da tabela
        
        $queryexec1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
        
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO tabela (chapa, departamento, setor) VALUES ('$chapa', '$departamento', '$setor')";
        
       $queryexec2 =  mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
        
    }
    
    if($queryexec1 && $queryexec2 !== FALSE)
        {
            echo "Dados enviados com sucesso!";
        }
    else
        {
            echo "Erro";
        }
```

Comment: Você não deveria dar o TRUNCATE **fora** do loop?

Comment: Cara deu certo! Valeu, sou novo na programação então algumas coisas passam desapercebidas!! Muito obrigado!!